# Error on Pattern matching with subgroups - neither greedy nor ungreedy qualifiers work

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to separate the text and the prefix/postfix in a word document. It's a ZIP file where I take part `word/document.xml` which looks like

```
^.*<w:body> 
...this is the text... 
<w:sectPr[^>]*><some_selfclosing_tags/>*</w:sectPr>
</w:body>.*$
```

The problem is that I can't determine the Pattern engine to put  *optional*

```
 <w:sectPr>...</<w:sectPr>
```

in the postfix group with the `</w:body>`.
It works neither with greedy `?` nor with ungreedy `??` qualifiers as shown below:

```
Pattern.compile("^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)"
+"((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>)?"
+"\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL)

Pattern.compile("^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)"
+"((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>)??"
+"\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

Here is a simplified version of the issue:

```
String doc="<?xml version=\"1.0\"><w:document><w:body> ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space=\"720\"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>";
Pattern rxv[]=new Pattern[]
        {Pattern.compile("^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)" 
                        +"((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>)?" 
                        +"\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL)
        ,Pattern.compile("^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)" 
                        +"((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>)??" 
                        +"\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL)
        };
ApplStr.ckRx(doc, rxv);
```

The above yields on System.out:

```
rx0:^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)((?:w:sectPr[^>]*>\s*(?:<\w+[^/>]*/>\s*)*</w:sectPr\s*>)?\s*</w:body\s*>.*)$
rx0Grp0:
<?xml version="1.0"><w:document><w:body> ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
rx0Grp1:
<?xml version="1.0"><w:document><w:body>
rx0Grp2:
 ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr>
rx0Grp3:
</w:body></w:document>

rx1:^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*)((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\s*(?:<\w+[^/>]*/>\s*)*</w:sectPr\s*>)??\s*</w:body\s*>.*)$
rx1Grp0:
<?xml version="1.0"><w:document><w:body> ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
rx1Grp1:
<?xml version="1.0"><w:document><w:body>
rx1Grp2:
 ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr>
rx1Grp3:
</w:body></w:document>
```

What I want is for the `<w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr>` to be in Group 3 not in Group 2.

Comment: sorry - I forgot to use the Ctrl-K for the inline code quotes.

Comment: The problem is that I can't determine the Pattern engine to put optional  in the postfix group with the . It works neither with greedy ? nor with ungreedy ?? qualifiers as shown below:

Comment: The optional part is <w:sectPr>...</w:sectPr>

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser?

Comment: If you remove `<w:sectPr[^>]*><some_selfclosing_tags/>*</w:sectPr>` your regex will still match the string. The only problem I see that you are missing one backslash before `\s` in `+"\s*</w:body`. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: The backslash before \s was a transcription error.

Comment: I'd like to keep it as simple as possible (there already is a lot of complexity around this) - that is why I did not use the xml parser here. What I want is for the `<w:sectPr>...</w:sectPr>` to be in group 3 not in group 2. This is a regex issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/ would simplify a lot of the work that you are trying to do. You have to consider that the maintainance of these regex sucks, whereas jaxb simplifies a lot of the work you are putting right now.

Comment: Unfortunately using the xml parser is not an option right now. However, the more I look at it the more it seems to me that this is an error in the Pattern/Matcher engine. Is there a way to check this with Oracle? May be it's been already fixed. System.getProperty("java.version")=1.6.0_31

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the substring you need as part of Group 2, you need to use lazy matching in Group 2 with `.*?`:

```
^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*?)((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>‌)?\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/aWyr37)

```
String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"><w:document><w:body> ...text... <w:sectPr><w:cols w:space=\"720\"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>";
String rx = "^(.*<w:body[^>]*>)(.*?)((?:<w:sectPr[^>]*>\\s*(?:<\\w+[^/>]*/>\\s*)*</w:sectPr\\s*>)?\\s*</w:body\\s*>.*)$";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"><w:document><w:body>
 ...text... 
<w:sectPr><w:cols w:space="720"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```